# make group by column list shorter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

```
CREATE TABLE a(id integer primary key, myValue int);
CREATE TABLE b(id integer);
INSERT INTO a VALUES(1,10),(2,20);
INSERT INTO b VALUES(1),(1);

SELECT b.id, a.myValue 
FROM b
JOIN a ON b.id = a.id
GROUP BY b.id;
```

gets me Msg 8120, Level 16 (Column a.myValue is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause). But since a.id is a primary key, engine could deduce that a.myValue is uniquely defined because a.id is. Just to make sure there is no getting around

```
SELECT b.id, a.myValue 
FROM b
JOIN a ON b.id = a.id
GROUP BY b.id, a.myValue;
```

OR

```
SELECT b.id, MAX(a.myValue) 
FROM b
JOIN a ON b.id = a.id
GROUP BY b.id;
```

Comment: "But since a.id is a primary key, engine could deduce that a.myValue is uniquely defined because a.id is" But it doesn't and if your column is contained in the select and isn't being aggregated it must appear in your GROUP BY. This is true in every major RDBMS (besides mysql pre-5.7). Whichever version you go with `Max()` or adding to Group by is up to you and your requirements for this query and expectations that your unique constraints and RI will also be true in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do requires an aggregation query.

That `id` is unique in `a` doesn't matter, because multiple rows in `b` might be matching.  Your example shows this.  If you return one value, why the `max()` instead of the `min()`, for instance?

Comment: interestingly SUM(a.myValue) returns 2*10=20. But a.myValue is uniquely defined. max(a.myValue)=min(a.myValue)=10.

Comment: @LudovicAubert . . . Because there are two rows.